# What is ${project.licensePath}?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to be able to set what license is used in the comment block at the top of a netbeans file. When I look at the template, I see this:

```
<#assign licenseFirst = "/*">
<#assign licensePrefix = " * ">
<#assign licenseLast = " */">
<#include "${project.licensePath}">
```

If this were to actually place a license at the top of my code, I would be delighted. The question is, how do I set `${project.licensePath}`, and what should I set it to for, say, the GPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an easier way.

Here's how to change the license for all new files you create in a project of yours:

1. Right click on the project icon
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on License Headers
4. Select Apache License 2.0 (or whatever) from the drop-down list

Done

[image: Changing project license on NetBeans 7.4]

Answer (score 17):

Using NetBeans 7.4, go to Template manager

[image]

Navigate to "Licenses"

[image]

you can add, use, modify, duplicate or delete a license file.

If you want to add a custom license you name it with

> "license-blablabla.txt"

(you can save the file whenever you want) and then you can select it from "Add" option.

Then go to your project files and open project.properties

[image]

and append a new line

```
project.license=blablabla
```

When you create a new class you will see your license file content on the header (blablabla is the suffix of your template filename).

If you want to use an existent template it's so easy, go to Licenses in the Template Manager and select a License, then right click and "properties", you can see the name of the file and then configure your project

[image]

[image]

and should work

[image]

**EDIT**

I don't know where the default license files are stored (and is not relevant) but if you try to use an incorrect filename you will get

> Error reading included file
>   Templates/Classes/Templates/Licenses/license-apache201.txt

**EDIT**

According to the comments in a [netbeans bug 236159](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236159) the folder is created in the user's home when you add or modify a template but I can't find it.